# Failed loading XML Start tag expected '<' not found

Tags: xml

I keep getting two messages on screen as soon as I enter my site "[FAILED LOADING XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8qx4.png)" or refresh a page after dismissing message and moving to a new tab, i.e from HOME to Subscribe.
The site works 100%, the only problem is that messages.
Link to live site: [CyberSec.group](http://cybersec.group). 
I'm using Joomla 3.6.5 and the default Protostar template, together with a few additional addons, modules and components.
The messages I get is not in any particular module, so it is kind of hard for me to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error message with the linked page. What browser do you view it in?

Comment: I used Google Chrome

Comment: when I use Internet Explorer to go the the site it does exactly the same... I opened IE and manually typed the address in the address bar

Comment: Please add a picture of the error message.

Comment: That error message is actually in the HTML source, so we cannot help you. The backend-code is your issue and we cannot see that.

Comment: in question see "FAILED LOADING XML" it is a clickable link that opens the screenshot in the parent window.

Comment: @DavidG I am not sure how to add an image to the comments

Comment: @Barend: Better edit your question than comment on your own question with additional info.

Comment: So there is no assistance or pointers you can give? no Ideas that might help?